# I am unable to get the value of a select html within a few divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that handles the select2 according to what is done with select1. Why does the following script not work when the `<select>` is  within several divs ?

HTML:

```
<div id="old_div">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cargo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
                <?php foreach($cargos as $row) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->id_cargo.'" >'.$row->nome_cargo.''.$row->id_cargo.'</option>';     
                } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nível Cargo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
                <?php foreach($nivel as $linha2) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$linha2->id_cargo.'" >'.$linha2->num_nivel.'</option>';
                } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="new_div">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change',"#select1", function() { 
    var id = $(this).val().trim();
    $(this).next('#select2').find('option').hide();
    var $options = $(this).next('#select2').find('option[value=' + id + ']');
    $options.show(); 
    $options.first().attr('selected',true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements

So when you try the next method, it will try to find an element at the same level with the ID `select2`. As the ID is unique, you don't need to find it as sibling. You can just find it in the document:

```
 $("#select2").find('option').hide();
```

Comment: I understand , however it was still not enough , see my problem altogether :  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YEQx/38/).  

when replacing  $(this).next('.select2').find('option').hide(); with   $('#select2').find('option').hide();  It worked! but it was not enough , it worked only in the first select , remove all divs , works for all selects

Comment: I hope you have understood me , I'm a little confused about it .

Comment: I'm not sure what's the behavior you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Because its not next. [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) is for selecting sibling elements.

Replace `$(this).next('#select2')` with `$('#select2')`.

And by the way if you know element's id you don't actually need any other context. Since ids *must be unique* within the document.

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` only searches sibling elements, so if `#select2` doesn't have the same parent as `#select1` then `next()` won't reach it.

Fortunately, there's no reason to use `.next` -- `$('#select2')` will find the node just as easily on its own.